# MVC 5 Partial View - Model confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a model called "Slider"

```
using System;
using NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode;
using NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Conformist;

namespace BarMotors.Models
{
public class Slider
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Photo{ get; set; }
    public virtual string LeftText{ get; set; }
    public virtual string RightText { get; set; }
    public virtual int SortOrder{ get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DeletedAt { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsDeleted
    {
        get { return DeletedAt != null; }
    }
}

public class SliderMap : ClassMapping<Slider>
{
    public SliderMap()
    {
        Table("Sliders");
        Id(x => x.Id, x => x.Generator(Generators.Identity));
        Property(x => x.Photo, x => x.NotNullable(true));
        Property(x => x.LeftText);
        Property(x => x.RightText);
        Property(x => x.SortOrder, x => x.NotNullable(true));
    }
}
}
```

I also (now) have this controller;

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BarMotors.Models;
using NHibernate.Linq;

namespace BarMotors.Controllers
{
    public class SliderController : Controller
    {
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult Sliders()
        {
            List<Slider> model;
            new List<Models.Slider>();
            model = Database.Session.Query<Slider>().Where(s => s.DeletedAt == null).OrderBy(x=>x.SortOrder).ToList();

            return PartialView("_HomeSlider", model);
        }
    }
}
```

MAIN view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Homepage";
}
<h1>Homepage</h1>
@Html.Action("Sliders", "Slider")
```

Partial view

```
@model BarMotors.Models.Slider

@{
    Layout = null;
}
//do something in loop of Slider
```

In SliderController I cannot pass var model to the partial view I either get Iqueryable, ienumerable or errors along the lines of;

**LIST of Models.Slider is not assignable to type models.Slider**

Many thanks
Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are trying to assign the list to a the model but you have declared a model which is not list type so you either want to declare it as a list type or select firstordefault from the result

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    /* ... your code ... */

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Sliders()
    {
        var model = new Models.Slider();

        model = Database.Session.Query<Slider>().Where(s => s.DeletedAt == null).OrderBy(x=>x.SortOrder).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

        return PartialView("your-view-name", model);
    }
}
```

Otherwise

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    /* ... your code ... */

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Sliders()
    {
        var model = new List<Models.Slider>();

        model = Database.Session.Query<Slider>().Where(s => s.DeletedAt == null).OrderBy(x=>x.SortOrder).ToList();

        return PartialView("your-view-name", model);
    }
}
```

And in partial View you have to change it to

```
@model List<BarMotors.Models.Slider>

@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Comment: `return PartialView("_HomeSlider", model);` is still telling me that; List<Slider> is not assignable to type Models.slider

Comment: Then you might be using the same in View . Can you post your Partial View

Comment: All code added in to my original post. There's just one slight thing I am missing I think - I just don't know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Updated the answer please check

Comment: Awesome no more errors, but my model is empty so there must be something wrong with the query or my nhibernate mapping as I have a row of data in the table! :(

Comment: That you have to check in backend database write the same query in db and see whether you are getting any results or not. If you got rows then probably your are doing something wrong if not then there is no data

Comment: Stupid me! I forgot to add my new mapping to my nHibernate.Configure method!!! haha

Answer (score 1):

If your slider has nothing to do with the parent model, you will probably want to use a child action.

Your controller would have an action like so:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    /* ... your code ... */

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Sliders()
    {
        var model = new Models.Slider();

        /* ... populate model ... */

        return PartialView("your-view-name", model);
    }
}
```

You would use the `HtmlHelper.Action()` method to request the child action from within the parent view:

```
<div>
    <!-- more view markup ... -->

    @Html.Action("sliders", "my")

</div>
```

When you call the `Html.Action` method in this way, the resulting view (normally a partial view) is rendered in-place in the current view. If you're familiar with PHP, it's somewhat similar to an `include` statement.

Comment: So, no viewmodel, but is "my" surely that should be some sort of model?

Comment: No. Calling the Html.Action like that would, at most, need some parameters. It's not like Html.Partial, which does use a model.

Comment: So just so I understand what is "my" - what is it in reference to? Thanks Simon

Comment: You're calling an action. First argument is the action, the second is the controller. The example code uses MyController, so the second argument is "my".

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't know if it was a cpoy and paste typo or something. Thanks for clearing that up.